LOR from Digital Circuits Course Professor (No projects or work done with the prof)
I had achieved the highest possible grade in this course (Digital Circuits) and most likely in the top 5/180 of this specific course, although I was very active in class I didn't really have any communication with the professor outside class hours. We didn't have any projects/assignments during the semester and haven't worked with him. He is happy to write me an LOR and asked me to draft one, however now I am worried that it would not be really strong as the prof wouldn't be able to cite enough evidence to show that I am a good student and fit for the summer research program.
I have two questions:

Would it be fine if the prof cited a course project I completed from another course (minor in data science and artificial intelligence) as well as another project related to Digital Circuits course taught by him but being pursued separately by a group of students?
Note: My research proposal of choice is a junction of computer architecture, VLSI, FPGA prototyping and artificial intelligence.

Would citing ability to solve difficult/creative problems posed in the exams/quizzes be relevant? This definitely seems to be weaker than being a testament to working on projects.


I am open to any suggestions to strengthen my LOR, the professor probably would guide me once I provide him with a draft but I want to make sure I take time to think about this so that he can work from something that is decent so that it is neither a burden and I benefit from a strong LOR.

Sorry, but I need to suggest that this is probably not the best option for a letter writer. The only evidence they have is how you did in one course and it wasn't a research oriented course, not did you have extensive communication with them along the way. If you asked a lot of questions in class, then you might stand out in their mind (in a good way), but that isn't really enough without other supporting elements.
However, if the letter is for masters study, rather than doctoral applications, it might not be so bad as the standards are lower, unless the masters is research focused rather than course based.
For a good LoR for a research program, the writer has to be able to honestly and confidently predict your success in that program and thereafter. Anything short of that is wasted for a high quality program.
I don't know how you could write a draft that would express that requirement. I'd think that the best you could do is give them a checklist of your accomplishments in that and similar courses, including pointing them to other professors who would have a high opinion of you. Include something in your checklist about the relationship, if any, between that course and your overall goals.

Sorry, I forgot to mention that this is for an REU. Does that help? The program doesn't mandate prior research experience however it could be a criterion for selection. I also did what you suggested by handing the professor my CV and transcript in the mail requesting them for an LOR, I mentioned my research proposal of choice and how this specific course could be relevant academic experience.
Is there anything else I could do?
